# synchronous queries on oracledb using aysync in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, express, node-async

i am very new to nodejs. I am using oracledb and want to make the queries in synchronous order. So once 1st query is executed then output of the query will be used in second query. i looked at async.waterfall and wrote below code. is it correct way to call function in synchronous way ? Thanks in Advance. it may be possible that 1st query takes more time than second.

```
var update = function(fnParam1, fnParam2){  
    oracledb.maxRows = 10000;   
oracledb.getConnection(
            {
            user          : dbConfig.user,
            password      : dbConfig.password,
            connectString : dbConfig.connectString
            },

function(err, connection)
            {
                if (err) { console.log(err.message); return; }
                async.waterfall([
                                 function(callback) {
                                     connection.execute("select column1 from table1 where param1 =:nm",[fnParam1], 
                                     function(err, result)
                                     {
                                        if (err) { console.log(err); return; }
                                            column1 = String(result.rows[0][0]);
                                     });
                                     callback(null, column1,connection);
                                 },
                                 function(column1, connection,callback) {
                                    connection.execute("select count(*) from table2 where column1 = :par1 and column2= :par2",[column1,fnParam2], 
                                    function(err, result)
                                    {
                                         if (err) { console.log(err); return; }
                                         var count = String(result.rows[0][0]);
                                         console.log("count result:" + count)
                                    });
                                    callback(null, count);
                                 }
                                 ],
                                 function (err, result) {
                                    console.log("Done" + result);
                                });
                });
};
```

Comment: Code looks fine, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just taking a quick look at the code, I noticed your "callback" invocations are not in the callback functions that are passed to execute. This means your going to the next step in your waterfall before you have the results from the execute method. Here's your code slightly modified to demonstrate what I mean. Also, don't forget to release your connection when you're done with it.

```
var update = function(fnParam1, fnParam2){  
    oracledb.maxRows = 10000;   
oracledb.getConnection(
            {
            user          : dbConfig.user,
            password      : dbConfig.password,
            connectString : dbConfig.connectString
            },

function(err, connection)
            {
                if (err) { console.log(err.message); return; }
                async.waterfall([
                                 function(callback) {
                                     connection.execute("select column1 from table1 where param1 =:nm",[fnParam1], 
                                     function(err, result)
                                     {
                                        if (err) { console.log(err); return; }

                                        column1 = String(result.rows[0][0]);
                                        callback(null, column1, connection);
                                     });
                                 },
                                 function(column1, connection, callback) {
                                    connection.execute("select count(*) from table2 where column1 = :par1 and column2= :par2",
                                    [column1,fnParam2], 
                                    function(err, result)
                                    {
                                         if (err) { console.log(err); return; }
                                         var count = String(result.rows[0][0]);
                                         console.log("count result:" + count);
                                         callback(null, count);
                                    });
                                 }
                                 ],
                                 function (err, result) {
                                    console.log("Done" + result);
                                });
                });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i didn't get your clarification. can you explain me with this example?